# Is it possible to find the MAC address of a turned off computer somewhere in my LAN?

Tags: networking, router

I know I can ping and find the MAC address in my local ARP table.

But what if a computer I want the address to is not started and can't respond to ping etc. and I can't reach it physically. Is there somewhere I can find this MAC address?

For example in routers or in DNS tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant.
Unless you have any mac-based rule on the switchport

Edit:
 dns reservations ( as you mentioned ) and dhcpd leases can work too.

Comment: Yes, DHCP leases would work, unfortunately it uses a fixed IP set locally.

Answer (score 7):

you may be able to find it in the Arp Cache of a system that had discovered the computer, if you know the downed PCs IP address.

in Windows:

```
arp -a
```

in Linux

```
arp
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but that computer wasn't listed. 
I ran arp -a from a Windows 2012 Server which is a Domain Controller and DNS server.
The client PC i want to find was connected to it about 12 hours before and are joined to the same domain.

Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

If the computer has BIOS set up for remote start, you should be able to send a "magic packet" to it to turn it on and then wait for its startup for network access.

Look for "Wake on LAN".

Comment: Umm you need the MAC address to use Wake on LAN, and the question is all about how he doesn't have the MAC address.

Comment: This was actually the reason for asking, i needed the MAC address to be able to do a WOL. :)

Comment: It is hard to do, but with a self-written application, you can turn on this computer by sending magic packets in local network that would just try every MAC address. The scope would be limited if you know the Ethernet adapter manufacturer (first digits of MAC). This would take much time and in effect you would turn on all the computers in local network, that have WOL active.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this situation recently and kind of went into how I'd find the MAC. Here are some of the things I did to get there:

1. If you have a Windows Server and the device has a dynamic or reserved IP, look at the DHCP server (mentioned in another answer). You'll find the MAC address in there for the server you want. (in fact, is the target device has a static IP, converting it to a reservation might later help you gather this info if you needed it).
2. arp -a: It'll work if the target machine was online recently, if not you may be out of luck.
3. Go low-tech - look for a invoice or order of the device you have, that sometimes lists interfaces and MAC addresses.
4. If the device is in front of you, look for stickers on the back or bottom, they often also include device (MAC) addresses.
5. Switches and routers do contain logs of devices that were connected and their corresponding MAC addresses.
6. Use a tool like WakeMeOnLAN to scan for devices that might be broadcasting.
7. If the target is a Dell server and you have OpenManage option with an interface, accessing that will show the underlying hardware of the machine (including the MAC address).

Just some ideas. I eventually found the MAC address in logs I kept when installing the target computer.

Comment: If you have a managed switch, it might be in the mac address table.  You'd need to know which port the computer is plugged into, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Asked a long time ago, but if you have access to a router in the network it might have a list of devices that are used in the network, some models show MAC address aswell.